# Blogroll import/export with categories and descriptions

Tags: links, import, export, blogroll

Is there an easy way (a plugin maybe?) to export and then import into a different WordPress installation all links in the blogroll including descriptions and categories?

I know you can export links by going to /wp-links-opml.php, but I believe doing it this way you loose the link descriptions. When importing, I'd like links to be put in their categories - if the categore does not exist it should be created.

I would prefer a way to do this without hacking any core WordPress files if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export/import the [wp_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_links) database table using PhpMyAdmin or similar database tool. Just make sure in the file that exports you change the database name at the top of the file to the name of the database in your destination wordpress site.

Note that importing the table will remove any links that you currently have in the destination Wordpress install.